# Determining if a set of vectors spans a space. Why does the determinant have to be nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

and I'm wondering when determining the span, why does the determinant have to be non zero? If the determinant was zero, couldn't the random vector have many non-unique solutions? And if a random vector could be represented by several different combinations of the vectors... wouldn't the vectors still span R^3?

Comment: Check out the [Inverse Matrix Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html), particularly points 3, 6, 7, and 19. One of the problem of doing linear algebra with determinants is that proving all the lovely properties of determinants is horrible, and the intuition behind it is not straight forward at all. I would convince yourself by other means (e.g. directly solving) that these systems of equations have unique solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a vector that can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$ in more than one way,  then the vectors are linearly dependent.   For, call the vector $v$.  We'd have $$\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n=v=\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n$$.  Then since at least one $\alpha_i\not=\beta_i$, we have the following nontrivial linear combination equal to zero: $$(\alpha_1-\beta_1) v_1+\dots+(\alpha_n-\beta_n)v_n=0$$.

So, in this situation, say we are in $\mathbb R^3$, and we have $3$ vectors (the columns of a matrix).  Call the matrix $A$.  We know the image is the span of the columns.   Say $Ax=v$ has more than one solution for some $v$ (that is, $\operatorname{det}A=0$)  as above.  Then the $3$ vectors couldn't span, because they would be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the analogy for the determinant, that the length/area/volume... of a $N$-dimensional parallelepiped is equal to $|\det(V)|$ where $v$ is a set of vectors.

Take a $2$ dimensional example where the vectors point in different directions. The abs(determinant) will be the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors.

Whereas, if the vectors are linearly dependent, they will have area $0$ because they form a degenerate parallelogram.

If we extend this to $3$ dimensions and a set of linearly dependent vectors, one of the vectors may lie in the plane spanned by the two other vectors. Therefore, it will have $0$ volume.